Install issues with composer syntax and patch errors done individually for D10 install
HELP.  Is it okay for patch errors during install on Drupal10?  and other issues...
For installing Civicrm on Drupal 10 following instructions at
//docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal/
When I try the commands
cd (to root of drupal, above web folder with json files)
composer config extra.enable-patching true
composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}
I get the error:
Could not find a matching version of package civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}.
Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available
in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
After that I also tried temp uninstall of drush prior as suggested for Drupal 9, no difference.
composer remove drush/drush
composer config extra.enable-patching true
composer config minimum-stability dev
However still fails same.
So that composer syntax is not working for me.
But I can make some progress if I do it individually like
composer require civicrm/civicrm-core
composer require civicrm/civicrm-packages
composer require civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8
The civicrm-core throws patch errors:
(replaced in example errors the https w/ ***** for posting limits)
Cannot apply patch *****//raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/9d93748a36c7c5d44422911db1c98fb2f7067b34/tools/scripts/composer/patches/civicrm-custom-patches-zetacompoents-mail.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch ****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/5506f4ce5d46799857b4f4ddf34069e7541e9cc5/tools/scripts/composer/zetacomponents-php-81-civicrm-custom.patch
Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/a6a0ff13d2a155ad962529595dceaef728116f96/tools/scripts/composer/patches/net-smtp-patch.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/74e25f27bb3be32519657539afe8a285c6c99a08/tools/scripts/composer/patches/mail_mime_crm_3133.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/36319938a5bf26c1e7e2110a26a65db6a5979268/tools/scripts/composer/patches/pear-mail.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/2ad420c394/tools/scripts/composer/pear_db_civicrm_changes.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/adrienrn/php-mimetyper/pull/15.patch
Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/adrienrn/php-mimetyper/pull/17.patch
.... allowing compile .....
Using version ^5.78 for civicrm/civicrm-core


composer require civicrm/civicrm-packages  Throws more patch errors

Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch //raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/9d93748a36c7c5d44422911db1c98fb2f7067b34/tools/scripts/composer/patches/civicrm-custom-patches-zetacompoents-mail.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/5506f4ce5d46799857b4f4ddf34069e7541e9cc5/tools/scripts/composer/zetacomponents-php-81-civicrm-custom.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/a6a0ff13d2a155ad962529595dceaef728116f96/tools/scripts/composer/patches/net-smtp-patch.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/74e25f27bb3be32519657539afe8a285c6c99a08/tools/scripts/composer/patches/mail_mime_crm_3133.patch
Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/36319938a5bf26c1e7e2110a26a65db6a5979268/tools/scripts/composer/patches/pear-mail.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/2ad420c394/tools/scripts/composer/pear_db_civicrm_changes.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/adrienrn/php-mimetyper/pull/15.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/adrienrn/php-mimetyper/pull/17.patch
.... allowing compile ...
Using version ^5.78 for civicrm/civicrm-packages


composer require civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8  throws more patch errors

 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/adrienrn/php-mimetyper/pull/15.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/adrienrn/php-mimetyper/pull/17.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/9d93748a36c7c5d44422911db1c98fb2f7067b34/tools/scripts/composer/patches/civicrm-custom-patches-zetacompoents-mail.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/5506f4ce5d46799857b4f4ddf34069e7541e9cc5/tools/scripts/composer/zetacomponents-php-81-civicrm-custom.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/a6a0ff13d2a155ad962529595dceaef728116f96/tools/scripts/composer/patches/net-smtp-patch.patch
 Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch *****://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/74e25f27bb3be32519657539afe8a285c6c99a08/tools/scripts/composer/patches/mail_mime_crm_3133.patch
.... allowing compile ....
Using version ^5.78 for civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8

NOTE
I had to GRANT TRIGGER for database, still had unknown DB error so for now I granted all privileges to sql user on databse which I do not like to do then I was able to run cv tools to setup data for civicrm.
After all that I still get errors on accessing civicrm webpage /civivicrm
like
[Tue Oct 29 16:32:03.188115 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 47817:tid 36541568768] [client 97.68.180.217:63110] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception IntlException: "Constructor failed" at ******/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Utils/Money.php line 249'

If you try applying one of the patches manually, does it work? e.g. git apply something.patch. Regarding civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8} syntax giving an error - are you on windows by chance? That syntax won't work on windows. Also what php version?

The first road bump is the composer command fails with suggested syntax: 
  composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}
So as to why that happened I think it may be the syntax is not good for Bourne Shell.
The shell I was using was the freebsd bourne shell.
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

I switched user to tsch shell to see if any different.
% echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh

Well okay the syntax for composer works in the tcsh shell but not pure bourne shell.  
FYI starting with FREEBSD 14 the default shell is sh 
So onward to the other problems.
  grr... comments wrapped.
yes I will try doing the patches by hand.

new to stack exchange, having problems answering in limited lenght and format of comments.  I am reposting this issue on civicrm chat ~drupal and will post back resolutions..... I am very disappointed in stack exchange atm.

Here is link to Civicrm Chat
https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/drupal/bmy5xw9wabftucc4mdsb8txxwy

PS.  yes if I go to the folder with the file to be patched, wget the patch, I can manually apply the patch.  But I have to be in the folder, like ./vendor/adrienrn/php-mimetyper

Solved for initial install,  We are on FREEBSD with default shell was /bin/sh so the syntax is different than bash, try /bin/tsch and it will work with composer command suggested.  THE OTHER ISSUE for patching is that cweagans/composer-patches stable is using as a hack the option --no-backup-if-mismatch that gnupatch supports but is not supported by FREEBSD patch.   We used /usr/ports/devel/patch and linked gnu patch instead and the install completed.  You may be able to use a devel version of cweagans/composer-patches that was fixed.  Note the verbose details are in civicrm chat ~ drupal.

Solved for initial install, We are on FREEBSD with default shell was /bin/sh so the syntax is different than bash, try /bin/tsch and it will work with composer command suggested. THE OTHER ISSUE for patching is that cweagans/composer-patches stable is using as a hack the option --no-backup-if-mismatch that gnupatch supports but is not supported by FREEBSD patch. We used /usr/ports/devel/patch and linked gnu patch instead and the install completed. You may be able to use a devel version of cweagans/composer-patches that was fixed. Note the verbose details are in civicrm chat ~ drupal.
